# Filtering available Gradle tasks by task group

Tags: filtering, report, gradle, task

With the command `gradle tasks` one can get a report of all available tasks. Is there any way to add a parameter to this command and filter tasks by their task group.

I would like to issue a command like `gradle tasks group:Demo` to filter all tasks and retrieve a list of only those tasks that belong to the task group called `Demo`.

Comment: You should change the accepted answer: Gradle 5.1+ supports it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From v5.1, you can do this: `gradle tasks --group=<group-name>`

[Gradle docs.](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:listing_tasks)

Answer (score 6):

You can do so by adding the following task to your build script:

```
task showOnlyMyTasks << {
    tasks.each {
        task -> if (task.group == 'My task group name') {
        println(task.name)
        }
    }
}
```

And then run:`gradle showOnlyMyTasks`

If you need only the list, you can use `gradle -q`

Answer (score 2):

*Old answer: There is no such feature. Feel free to suggest new features at http://forums.gradle.org.*

**Now available since Gradle 5.1**, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54341658/4433326

Comment: Everybody: it can be done from v5.1, refer to my answer.